# Can we move to previous activity in Sequential type workflow?

Tags: c#, windows, workflow, workflow-foundation

My application is a kind of wizard in which user can move forward or can also move to previous activity. We are using a long running workflow, and we create bookmark after each activity completes and then user make call for next activity in which we resume the previous bookmark and create bookmark for next available activity.

I am able to create forward only wizard using workflows but not able to move back to previous activity.

Please help if anybody knows a solution for it, if we can move to previous activity in Sequential type workflow.

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, I would advise to use a State Machine workflow, which provides much more dynamic capabilities, based on the input event and can transition from any state to any other state, as long as a transition is defined: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264171(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264171%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you want to have this behavior in a sequential workflow, I believe you will have to play with a loop activity so that you can return back to the loop or exit, based on the user's input.  But this doesn't seem trivial, especially if you have multiple steps in your workflow.